# WebGrid in MVC is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have WebGrid in many views of my project and all were working properly until a few days back. Right now, though, when try to add a new view with WebGrid, it's showing the error:

> The type or namespace name 'WebGrid' could not be found (are you
>   missing any directive or any assemble reference)

When I run the app now, all the Views are having the same problem. I would be grateful for any suggestions as to what might have caused this.

Comment: obviously something has happened to WebGrid.dll in your project. Is it still present in `/bin` folder? Do you have other component that references different version of this library? Can you go back in source control and check what has happened in the code just before it stopped working?

Comment: just i was removed the System.Web.Helpers from references and added again then it is accepted but i  got another error while running the programme that was       An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll but was not handled in user code                                                                       Additional information: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationDescription' from assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: Seems like `System.Web.Helpers` is of a wrong version to what it was before.

Comment: i didn't change any thing i just removed from references and add the same thing as it is. after i am getting these error and previous webgrid is solved. so i was tryed the same thing like remove the Microsoft.owin.Security and it is not working

Comment: it seems that you removed the `system.web.helpers` v4 (for .net 4) and again added the v2 of it (for older version of .net). check if the correct version has been added to your references